# mongo terminal, check database exist function

Tags: mongodb

It is a `mongo` terminal problem,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
echo "Hello $USER."
echo "--------------------------"

mongo < myScript.js
```

with `myScript.js` as

```
if (hereAFunctionCheckExistsDatabase('myDatabase'))
   doSomething()
exit
```

Of course `show dbs` work, but is a echo, I need a function.

---

My `mongo`:

```
 MongoDB shell version: 2.4.10
 connecting to: test
```

Comment: SOLVED: `db.getMongo().getDBNames().indexOf('myDatabase')!=-1` ... delete question??

Comment: You can post it as answer to your own question. Will helpful to others in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
function hereAFunctionCheckExistsDatabase(db) {
   return (db.getMongo().getDBNames().indexOf(db)!=-1);
}
```

---

Mongo have also a catalog of namespaces, try this

```
db.system.namespaces.find( { name: /myDatabase\./ } );
```

...

Comment: Hello, I need only check dbName exist, not need collectionName

Comment: ... hum... perhaps `db.getMongo().getDBNames()`?

Comment: You can use db.getMongo().getDBNames() and then iterate this results to find it

Comment: Well, the  answer is `db.getMongo().getDBNames().indexOf('myDatabase')!=-1 `, you need edit the question to get my vote